# How to execute a Command Promt on Stored Procedure SQL Developer

Tags: cmd, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've been trying this:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "REPLACE" 
IS                                              
BEGIN

  host @"C:\Replace.bat";
  COMMIT;

END;
```

The log errors:

> Error: ORA-02083: el nombre de la base de datos tiene el carácter no
>   válido ':'

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't do this, not with a PL/SQL stored procedure at least.

First of all, HOST is a SQL*Plus command not a PL/SQL procedure or function you can call.

If you want to stick with a stored procedure - then take the contents of 'replace.bat' and rewrite in native PL/SQL.

If you simply MUST execute that script from inside the database itself (where PL/SQL runs by the way), then consider creating  SCHEDULER Job that will call out to SQL*Plus and run that script - assuming that the .bat script itself is some thing that calls out to SQL*Plus.

If you want to really reach out to the operating system from inside the database, you can also write a stored java procedure. That will invoke the JVM, and run your Java code, and you can do pretty much whatever you want provided you know how to code it.

**But.**

For the best answer and advice, you need to show/tell us just what 'replace.bat' does.

As for the  ORA-02083

The compiler is seeing the '@' character and is going into 'oh we must be seeing a DB_LINK coming up. So the next confusing thing it sees after that is the ':' character, which apparently isn't legal for a database name, which it's trying to find in the non-existing DB_LINk.

**One last thing:**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "REPLACE"
```

REPLACE is a reserved word for a reason. Quoting object names to get around reserved words will create WAY more problems or you than it will solve. Better to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REPLACE_STUFF
```

Comment: Thanks,

The file 'replace.bat' es this:

    @echo off
    Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in (file.txt) do (set ANT=%%i&echo !ANT:        =    N/A    ! >> kkk.txt)
    copy /y kkk.txt Ivan.txt
    del /q kkk.txt
 
This file replaces a string with another string in a txt file.

Comment: Why are you asking the database to do this?

Comment: Because I don't have actually the apps, only the database and I need the solution right now. Do you have an example for use SCHEDULE Jobs??

Comment: You can do all of that with a shell script and an OS job though. Tim AKA oracle-base has a nice walk through here https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/scheduler-enhancements-12cr1#external-script